# Camel only sends the message on startup, then stops

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have hopefully a trivial problem. I wrote super short 'program' for Apache Camel to read the context.xml and then do as it is told:

```
public class CamelBridge {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("camelContext.xml");        
    }
}
```

I connect between two JMS queues. The program works, but just when I start it. Then it stops sending messages. If I restart- it sends them all again. Is there something oviously wrong that I am missing here?

**Edit:**

I have updated my Main, but it does not help:

```
public class Bridge {

    private Main main;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Bridge bridge = new Bridge ();
        bridge.boot();
    }

    public void boot() throws Exception{
        main = new Main();
        main.enableHangupSupport(); 
        main.setApplicationContextUri("camelContext.xml");
        main.run();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

I think I found the issue (not the solution). After enabling tracing, I found the error message which reads:

*jms cannot find object in dispatcher with id --some id--*

And after some more digging I found that this is connected `clientLeasePeriod` in the remoting file. Any idea if it is possible to fix this kind of problem on Camel side?

Comment: Could you post your camelContext.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the problem was with the server on which the program was installed. The server thought that it resides on a public network, rather than private network (Windows Server 2012). After changing the network to private, the process worked correctly.

Note- the Camel did not give any errors regarding this, so this can be difficult to spot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent JVM from finishing

Check this example: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: JVM does not finish, I run it using Spring and it reacts to switching off any of this queues.

Comment: Do you know how to use it with xml file anyway?

Comment: xml file? do you mean use Spring DSL instead of Java DSL?

Comment: Yes Spring DSL, I am trying your solution with it, maybe it will help.

Comment: you can load XML like this:InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("route.xml");
   RoutesDefinition routes = context.loadRoutesDefinition(is);  context.addRouteDefinitions(routes.getRoutes()); But it wont resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you app contains only Main and xml file which configures Camel's context then context  will be destroyed (so your routes destroyed as well). Even if different context run JMS implementation on same JVM. Sergey link should help you.

If you want just make it work to test things, add while(true) as a last line of your main. Note this is not the best approach :).

Comment: I can see my context as active and JVM as working. If I shut down any of the endpoints- it complains. If I switch endpoints back on- it is all good.

Comment: That's right, because now main thread will block on main.run(). Does behavior of your jms oriented routes has changed in any way?